# Calculating the percentage of Difference between two columns as a separate column in the result

Tags: sql, oracle

I am stuck in a situation that needs percentage between two columns difference, for example: I have column "**AVERAGE_PRICE_2017**" values and column "**AVERAGE_PRICE_2016**"
values in numbers, Now I need that how much percentage of difference is between these two value.
Now the challenge is that the difference result could be in 0 or a negative number.
I tried below but didn't work out.

```
SELECT medicine_name,
  average_price_2017,
  average_price_2016,
  average_price_2017-average_price_2016 a,
  ROUND(a * 100.0 / AVERAGE_PRICE_2017, 1) AS Percent
FROM ST_COMPARE_ALL_4;
```

ERROR:

```
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'A'
06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 14 Column: 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use alias of any column directly to populate another column. Instead you should find the difference again while calculating percentage. Try the below query:

```
SELECT medicine_name,
  average_price_2017,
  average_price_2016,
  average_price_2017-average_price_2016 a,
  ROUND((average_price_2017-average_price_2016) * 100.0 / AVERAGE_PRICE_2017, 1) AS Percent
FROM ST_COMPARE_ALL_4;
```